# Exclude Some files from files locking in TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, tfs, file-locking

So I have a web project that minifies and condenses our javascript to a couple of files as a post build action. The problem is that in order to build the project correctly I have to check out the target files because otherwise the build fails because VS doesn't have write access to these files. Is there anyway to include these files in TFS but not require file locking for them? I've done something similar to this with SVN but I've been unable to find a way to do it in TFS.

Comment: Dumb question: I'm assuming the build system doesn't then check them back in? Why not just set the files writable instead of checking them out?

Comment: Tfs doesn't allow you to do that. When you change permissions on the disk they get reverted. Also each developer builds locally and I'd like to find a way to set it up so that each person doesn't have to manually change file permissions.

Comment: It does, and they don't, at least not without manual intervention (get specific + force + overwrite).  You will have a *writable conflict* if you do a get latest to new code or a get specific + force, but neither of these should be problems with your build system.

Comment: Tried setting them writable again and that works, I must have been doing something retarded. Thanks for the help. However, I'm still curious as to why I can't just tell TFS to not enforce file locking on specific files like I can in SVN via the svn:needs-lock prop, seems like that would be a feature that would get some use.

Comment: Good feedback.  I think our suggestions are to avoid locking at all, except on non-mergeable (binary) types.  So you can configure the types of files to enforce locks on, but not a specific path.  I see the use though, so I'll make sure this gets on our backlog.